# custom method in .filterHandler not being called

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to implement a custom filter handler for a single number display on a dashboard. I'm trying to use the `.filterHandler` method to define my own handler, but it doesn't seem to be calling that method at all.

Here is how I'm initializing the NumberDisplay

```js
const dim = this.data.cf.dimension((e) => e.mrn);

const currentEnrollmentsSingleStat = dc
      .numberDisplay("#enrollment-single-stat")
      .group(
        dim
          .groupAll()
          .reduceSum((d: Enrollment) =>
            d.type === "ACTIVE_ENROLL" && d.activeNow ? 1 : 0
          )
      )
      .valueAccessor((d) => d)
      .formatNumber(d3.format(".4~s"))

currentEnrollmentsSingleStat.filterHandler(function (dimension, filter) {
  console.debug("[EnrollmentDashboard] - activeEnrollments filter handler:", dimension, filter)

  return 0
})
```

No matter what filters I apply, via clicking on other charts' bars, I can't seem to get the console log inside the `.filterHandler` function to display.

Comment: The `filterHandler` is only called when the *current chart* is being filtered. Other charts will get `.redraw()` called and will pull the new filtered data using `group.all()` (or possibly `group.value()` for the number display). If this doesn't answer your question, please edit it to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That makes sense why it isn't being called. This gives me more insight on my real problem.

I have a list of objects that have a `start` and `end` date. My bar chart's dimension is based off of the `start` timestamp's month.

I need my single stat to be based off of _both_ the `start` and `end` timestamps. I.E. if August is selected on the bar chart, I need to count the number of records that were "active" in August (`start` is at least before the end of August and the `end` is at least after the start of August)

Comment: Asked a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71844836/crossfilter-js-dimension-for-active-records)