# crossfilter.js - count intervals contained within a range

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

My dataset consists of records with `start` and `end` timestamps.

The barchart's dimension is based of the `end` timestamp:

```js
const dim = this.cf.dimension((item) => {
      switch (this.config.xAxis) {
        case "Month":
          return dayjs(item.timeEnd).format("YYYY.MM")
      ...
```

I have a NumberDisplay that needs to be based off *both* the `start` and `end` timestamps to display the number of "active" records. I.E. if August 2021 is filtered on the bar chart, I need to count all records that were "active" during that month (`start` <== end of August and `end` >== start of August).

I tried looking into [tag dimensions](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays), but I couldn't seem to get it working.

Comment: Interesting problem, and not something directly supported by crossfilter. There is a [time intervals example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/time-intervals.html) using an interval tree, but that searches for any intervals which intersect, not for containment. It doesn't look like the interval tree library supports containment.

Comment: How big is your data? If it's not huge you might try grabbing filtered records using some `dimension.top(Infinity)`, filter and count.

Comment: Upwards of 50k records

Comment: Hmm, thought I had a nice simplification of the problem, and I wrote an answer. But I missed a case so I have deleted it. (Item intervals could completely contain the range.) I think an interval tree could solve this but it's not in the API of the library used by the example.